# Downloading my existing project in google cloud using Gcloud SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, project, google-cloud-platform

I have created a project and uploaded it to google cloud using gcloud sdk. The machine I used for uploading is not working now. I am working on a different machine now.

How can I clone or download my previous project in gcloud sdk ?

I tried to download it using [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code) documentation, but `appcfg.py` is not found

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) tutorial to create a static website with html

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `appcfg.py` is no longer bundled by default into the more recent versions of the cloud SDK, it which case it needs to be installed separately. From [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code#troubleshooting) (emphasis mine):

> If you use the `gcloud` commands from the Cloud SDK, the `appcfg.py`
>   command is available at the following path:
>
> ```
> [INSTALL_PATH]/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py
> ```
>
> **If that path does not exist, run `gcloud components install app-engine-python` to install the App Engine SDK to your Cloud SDK
>   installation.**

Comment: I tried this too. But the SDK opens appcfg.py file instead of executing it. Finally, found a way to clone the project from repo using git hub